# ROS installation on Virtual Machine

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am a newbie to ROS and would like to get started with it. I have my computer with Windows 7 32 Bit OS. Would it be wise to install virtual machine and then to install Linux to have ROS platform for development or I should go on to buy a new computer with Linux as an OS to start with ROS. Basically, I do not want to invest in new computer until I get some expertise in ROS so was thinking to go with VM option.

What version of Linux and ROS would be best in my case?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226527/ros-installation-on-virtual-machine/) by [RobTool](https://answers.ros.org/users/25937/robtool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Virtual machine is a good way to start learning ROS, avoids issues with linux and hardware issues as you first start. Ubuntu 14.04 with Indigo ROS is the current long term support combination.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobTool](https://answers.ros.org/users/25937/robtool/) on 2016-02-13**:
So VMware is better?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-02-13**:
@robtool There is a pre-built [VM image from Nootrix](http://nootrix.com/software/ros-indigo-virtual-machine/) with these LTS versions (Ubuntu 14.04 / ROS Indigo), so it may save you some time. If I am not mistaken, there is also ready to use catkin workspace in `~/catkin_ws`.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-13**:
It's your decision, based on the information you have given it would seem wise to spend some time using a VM to get an idea of using ROS. Only you can say when buying a dedicated machine is a good cost/benefit decision. Given that you can try vm for no outlay it seems to make sense as a first step

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-13**:
You could also install Linux alongside windows and create a dual boot machine rather than buy an additional machine, bit I would be inclined to try a vm first to see if any of the more complicated/expensive options are worth it.